# Laravel route register cannot see register(RegisterRequest $request) at submit

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel registration form (code below). When I press the Submit button, it is supposed to read function `register(RegisterRequest $request)` in `class RegisterController`. Instead it returns to the function `showRegistrationForm()`. The register form appears again and is empty. Assuming that because `register` does not run, the register request is not completed. How do I complete a registration request?

`register.blade.php`

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register.post') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                            @error('name')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>

                        <label for="name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="lastname" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                            @error('name')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-7 offset-md-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Register') }}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

`web.php` routes

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    // Authentication Routes
    Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
    Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login.post');

    // Registration Routes
    Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register');
    Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register.post');
});
```

RegisterController.php

```
class RegisterController extends Controller {
use RegistersUsers;

protected $userRepository;

public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}

public function redirectPath()
{
    return route(home_route());
}

public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    abort_unless(config('access.registration'), 404);

    return view('client.auth.register')
        ->withSocialiteLinks((new SocialiteHelper)->getSocialLinks());
}

public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    abort_unless(config('access.registration'), 404);

    $user = $this->userRepository->create($request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'));

    if (config('access.users.confirm_email') || config('access.users.requires_approval')) {
        event(new UserRegistered($user));

        return redirect($this->redirectPath())->withFlashSuccess(
            config('access.users.requires_approval') ?
                __('exceptions.client.auth.confirmation.created_pending') :
                __('exceptions.client.auth.confirmation.created_confirm')
        );
    }

    auth()->login($user);

    event(new UserRegistered($user));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

}
```

RegisterRequest.php

```
class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest{

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:191'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:191'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:191', Rule::unique('users')],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required_if:captcha_status,true', 'captcha'],
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'g-recaptcha-response.required_if' => __('validation.required', ['attribute' => 'captcha']),
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: You have three rather large file sections. It may help others in helping you if you could slim your problem down to the minimum amount of code that represents your issue. For example, instead of the entire registration form fields, maybe just as a name field, or remove all the row and column structure elements so that it is only the inputs and functions.

Comment: as pointed by @Kevin you should read here on how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You might as well provide the relevant parts of RegisterRequest class